# Accessing non-public HttpWebRequest._HttpResponse in C#

Tags: c#, rest

I'm trying to authenticate against Google's OAuth using C# and in spite of my best efforts, I'm still getting 400 Bad Request.

So my little

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

never actually gets a response. My response object is never filled.

BUT google sends back data on 400s. You can see that if you point a browser at https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken

My question is how do I access that information in C#? It seems to be inside of a non-public member of the HttpWebRequest._HttpResponse, but it's in bytearray form and I can't read it or access it programatically.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to catch the thrown 404 exception, like this:

```
HttpWebResponse response;
try
{
    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    response = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
}
```

Its annoying, and IMO a bit of an oversight, but thats the only way if you are using the `HttpWebRequest` class.

Answer (score 0):

Your `response` object never gets filled because a [`WebException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.aspx) is being thrown by `request.GetResponse()` upon a 400 error.

Try something like this:

```
HttpWebResponse response;
bool isValid = false;

try
{
    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    isValid = true;
}
catch (WebException we)
{
    response = (HttpWebResponse)we.Response;
}

if (isValid)
{
    // the response was valid
}
else
{
    // the response returned a 400 error
}
```